# How do I use a query on a timestamp to filter down to "day of the week" and "hour"

Tags: google-sheets

Currently I am able to Query my data by the date in a timestamp but now I want to narrow it down to the hour and the day

=COUNT(QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$E, "Select A where A>=date '"&TEXT(B$5,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and A <= date '"&TEXT(B$6,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")

I am attempting to build a grid of when my responses come in by date and time over the hour
 Date ranges have to be dynamic.  I need to go look at a sample of data over a week or a sample of data over a year

How can I add a conditional time and day statement to this?

This is what I want to do
 Each cell will be it's own query formula[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1K3a.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFs(ArrayFormula(WEEKDAY(A:A)),"=1",ArrayFormula(hour(A:A)),"=8")
```

Where `a:a` is the array containing your timestamps. This example would populate the Monday at 8 am category.